# align ul next to each other dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I have the next fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cristi_mvp/e8UkN/4/
I want the columns to be displayed next to each other, instead of one over another.
Each column has different widths. 
I tried different things but they dont work.
Also I do not want to use css column.

It should be simple, but i just can't find the answer.
Thank you.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="header-main">
    <div class="header-main-menu">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li> <a href='#' title='Menu 1'> Menu 1</a>

                <ul>
                    <li>Column 1 lenght xxxx</li>
                    <li>Column 1</li>
                    <li>Column 1</li>
                    <li>Column 1</li>
                    <li>Column 1</li>
                    <li>Column 1</li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>Column 2 lenght</li>
                    <li>Column 2</li>
                    <li>Column 2</li>
                    <li>Column 2</li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>Column 3</li>
                    <li>Column 3</li>
                    <li>Column 3</li>
                    <li>Column 3</li>
                    <li>Column 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href='#' title='Menu 2'> Menu 2</a>

                <ul>
                    <li>Column 1-2</li>
                    <li>Column 1-2</li>
                    <li>Column 1-2</li>
                    <li>Column 1-2</li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>Column 2-2</li>
                    <li>Column 2-2</li>
                    <li>Column 2-2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.header-main-menu .menu {
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
.header-main-menu .menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.header-main-menu .menu li a {
    display: block;
    color: #00000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px 24px 6px 10px;
    display: block;
}
.header-main-menu .menu ul {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    /* Hide off-screen when not needed (this is more accessible than display:none;) */
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    z-index: 5000;
}
.header-main-menu .menu ul li {
    /*padding-top: 1px;*/
    /* Introducing a padding between the li and the a give the illusion spaced items */
    float: none;
    background-image: none;
    display: block;
    min-width: 120px;
}
.header-main-menu .menu ul a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* Stop text wrapping and creating multi-line dropdown items */
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 13px;
    padding: 6px 24px 2px 14px;
}
.header-main-menu .menu li:hover ul {
    /* Display the dropdown on hover */
    left: 0;
    /* Bring back on-screen when needed */
    fload:left;
}
.header-main-menu .menu li:hover a {
    /* These create persistent hover states, meaning the top-most link stays 'hovered' even when your cursor has moved down the list. */
}
.header-main-menu .menu li:hover ul a {
    /* The persistent hover state does however create a global style for links even before they're hovered. Here we undo these effects. */
    text-decoration: none;
    background: none;
}
.header-main-menu .menu li:hover ul li a:hover {
    /* Here we define the most explicit hover states--what happens when you hover each individual link. */
    background: #FF0000;
}
.header-main-menu .menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}
.header-main-menu .menu li:hover {
    background: #000;
}
.header-main-menu .menu ul li:hover {
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: can you make it clear? you want column as a dropdown???

Comment: As you can see in the fiddle, the columns are one over another. When I mouseover Menu 1 i should be able to see all the columns listed next to each other. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please add `padding: 0` to your code. Like this:

```
.header-main-menu .menu ul {
   color: #fff;
   float: left;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: It works but it stretches the Menu 1 as long as the columns show. I need the width of Menu 1 to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu
{
    display:block;
}
ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
}
ul li
{
    float:left;
    width:80px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#003366;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
}
a
{
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul li ul
{
    display:none;
}

ul li:hover ul
{
    display:block;
    margin-left:-50px;
}
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PFBM8/12/)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I need the Menu 1 "button" fixed width and the dropdown horizontally listed in columns. column1|column2|column3